# Add extra function when status bar is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I want my navigation bar to unhide when the status bar is tapped. Currently it's only scrolling my webview to the top. Anybody knows how to get this working? The webview can still scroll to top, this function doesn't need to be removed.

Comment: Overlay a `UIButton` on the status bar.

Comment: It is unclear to which tool it is related. Could you provide the information what tool you mean and provide the screen snapshot?

Comment: @DanielStorm That won't work because I have a navigationbar defined by a navigation controller. I'm not able to place a button over the statusbar :( unless i don't know how, if you could explain :)

Comment: @kazik1616 Apple provides a function that causes my webview to scroll to the top, and i want it also to show my previously hidden navigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIWindow` with the same dimensions as your status bar, add a `UIButton` to the `UIWindow`, and position it on top of your status bar.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let statusbarWindow = UIWindow()
    let statusbarButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup UIWindow
        statusbarWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width,
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height)
        statusbarWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
        statusbarWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

        // Setup UIButton
        statusbarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width,
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height)
        statusbarButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        statusbarButton.addTarget(self, action: "statusbarButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        statusbarWindow.addSubview(statusbarButton)
    }

    func statusbarButton(sender:UIButton!) {
        // Scroll UIWebView to top
        yourWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(0,0)
        // Unhide nav bar here
    }
```

**Apple Docs**: [**UIWindowLevel**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIWindowLevel), [**makeKeyAndVisible**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/makeKeyAndVisible).